# Interactive US Map Functionality

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I am working with a pretty cool interactive us map using jquert from newsignature (http://newsignature.github.com/us-map/). I am having trouble figuring out how I can enter unique information for each state when clicked on. In other words, when a user would click on Washington they would get certain information vs. when the click on Arkansas. Perhaps even the ability to have the content styled.

The current code I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#map').usmap({
    'stateSpecificStyles': {
      'AK' : {fill: '#0F253F'}
    },
    'stateSpecificHoverStyles': {
      'HI' : {fill: '#0F253F'}
    },

    'mouseoverState': {
      'HI' : function(event, data) {
        //return false;
      }
    },


    'click' : function(event, data) {
      $('#alert')
        .text('Click '+data.name+'  copy ')
        .stop()
        .css('backgroundColor', '#ff0')
        .animate({backgroundColor: '#ddd'}, 1000);
    }
  });


});
```

What I would like to see happen is when you click on a specific state it displays information regarding that state vs. the same info for each state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the state that they clicked on is in the `data.name` property. There are many ways to go about this. What have you tried?

```
$('#map').usmap({
  // The click action
  click: function(event, data) {
    var description = "No state info loaded for this state.";
    switch(data.name)
    {
        case 'IL':
            description = 'You clicked on the Land of Lincoln!';
            break;
        case 'MO':
            description = 'You clicked on the Show-Me State!';
            break;
        // etc
    }
    $('#clicked-state')
      .text(description)
      .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
  }
});
```

Actually, now that I look more at the documentation, you could also make state-specific methods like this:

```
$('#map').on('usmapclickIL', function(event, data) {
    $('#clicked-state')
      .text('You clicked on the Land of Lincoln!')
      .parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Right now I have not had any success with anything I have tried because I am not super confident in my js skills.

Comment: this is what i have now:$('#map').usmap({
     'stateSpecificStyles': {
       'AK' : {fill: '#0F253F'}
     },
     'stateSpecificHoverStyles': {
       'HI' : {fill: '#0F253F'}
     },
     
     'mouseoverState': {
       'HI' : function(event, data) {
         //return false;
       }
     },
     
     
     'click' : function(event, data) {
       $('#alert')
         .text('Click '+data.name+'  copy ')
         .stop()
         .css('backgroundColor', '#ff0')
         .animate({backgroundColor: '#ddd'}, 1000);
     }
   });

Comment: It would be easier to provide further help if you were more specific on what is not working like you expect it to. Also, when you ask questions here, if you can provide a small amount of code that demonstrates the issue, that would be helpful as well. And finally, the absolute best way to get help would be to create a demo at jsfiddle.net where people can see your code as a work in progress and comment on it.